# Compare values/data using CSV data set config in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Trying to compare the data/count between source and destination tables (SQL) as below through using CSV config in JMeter. is it possible to implement this way?.

[CSV config in JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAQSs.png)

just want to compare the count between STAGING and DW  for all tables. any thoughts on this..?

Comment: the issue is , I can't put the SQL query directly in JDBC request, as I have around 500 tables there that need to compare the data with different business scenarios and i can't create that many JDBC requests. so, I'm trying to pass the source and destination queries through using CSV config file and compare the respective query results between source and sink. Is that can be done by any way..?? see for sample CSV config [ i.stack.imgur.com/gAQSs.png ]

Answer (score 0):

Just define **Variable Names** so [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler could store the query execution output into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

1. In first JDBC Request sampler define "Variable Name" as `result1` (replace "SQL Query" with the relevant JMeter Variable name holding the value from the CSV file)

   [image]
2. In second JDBC Request sampler define "Variable Name" as `result2`

   [image]
3. That's it, now you will have the count of rows returned from the first JDBC Request sampler as `result1_1` and from the second as `result2_1`

   [image]
4. Now you can compare the values using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

   [image]

   in case of mismatch the relevant JDBC Request sampler will be marked as failed and you will be informed about the differences:

   [image]

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, thanks for the response. the issue is , I can't put the SQL query directly in JDBC request, as I have around 500 tables there that need to compare the data with different business scenarios and i can't create that many JDBC requests. so, I'm trying to pass the source and destination queries through using CSV config file and compare the respective query results between source and sink. Is that can be done by any way..??  see for sample CSV config [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAQSs.png ]